# How can I return a shared channel or data stream that can be consumed by multiple receivers?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

my goal/use case:

- Subscribe to a datafeed
- Publish to internal subscribers

Example use case: subscribe to stock prices, consume from multiple different bots running on different threads within the same app.

In other languages, I'd be using an RX Subject and simply subscribe to that from anywhere else and I can choose which thread to observe the values on (threadpool or same thread, etc).

Here is my attempt using a simulated data feed:

Code:

```
async fn test_observable() -> Receiver<Decimal> {
    let (x, response) = mpsc::channel::<Decimal>(100);

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        for i in 0..10 {
            sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
            x.send(Decimal::from(i)).await;
        }
    });

    response
}



#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut o = test_observable().await;
    while let Some(x) = o.recv().await {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

Questions:

- Is this the right approach? I normally use RX in other languages but it is too complicated in Rust so I resorted to using Rust channels. [RX for Rust](https://github.com/rxRust/rxRust)
- I think this approach won't work if I have multiple receivers. How do I work around that? I just want something like an RX observable, it should not be difficult to achieve that.
- Is this creating any threads?

Comment: I think you need to explain your use case in more detail. "[I]t is too complicated in Rust" – looks like [there simply isn't an Rx implementation for Rust](https://reactivex.io/languages.html). "I resorted to using Rust channels" there is no such things as "Rust channels". It's not a feature of the language like in Go. There are libraries that implement multi-consumer channels, e.g. [async-channel](https://github.com/smol-rs/async-channel). "Is this creating any threads?" Tokio's default runtime is multi-threaded.

Comment: @SvenMarnach thank you. I tried to explain myself better and added a link to the RX library for Rust.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I made some progress and posted another question. Looks like the right way is to use Streams which wraps a Receiver. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72063644/how-do-i-share-a-tokio-stream-between-tasks-confused-about-ownership

Comment: https://github.com/rxRust/rxRust not sure it provides multi subscription streams yet, but lots of useful stuff there already